# Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2012 linker when using /manifest:embed?

Tags: windows, performance, visual-studio-2012, embed, manifest

I've noticed a small program is taking ~15ms longer to invoke when compiled with vs2012 than it took in 2010.  This does not seem like much, but it can be called numerous times and we are seeing a ~2x slowdown in certain functionality due to this extra 15ms.

I have found a workaround which I document below, but my question is if this is something that I'm doing wrong, or if I'm seeing a bug in the way Visual Studio 2012 has implemented the /MANIFEST:embed option.  Sorry for the length of what follows, but I find it difficult to be both thorough and brief at the same time.

About my environment:

```
Windows 7 Enterprise x64 + Service Pack 1

c:\tmp>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60610.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

c:\tmp>mt
Microsoft (R) Manifest Tool version 6.2.9200.16384
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2012.
All rights reserved.
```

I can reproduce by starting a new empty project console application.  A single source file with this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string buf;
    while(std::cin >> buf)
    {
        std::cout << buf;
        buf="";
    }
}
```

When this is compiled by VS, it issues effectively this (I've taken the actual full-path commands from vs and cleaned them up so you can issue these from a VS2012 developer command prompt)-- take the above code and save as test.cpp, then in the same directory from a Developer Command Prompt For VS 2012 window, issue:

```
CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /sdl /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fd"test.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt test.cpp

link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:test.exe /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"test.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"test.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH test.obj
```

If you now view the resulting test.exe with notepad, you can see that the embedded manifest is this:

```
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

If I write a bat file with this line repeated 100 times:
`echo "Hello" | test.exe`
and execute it, it takes approximately 4.5s on my system (I used cygwin time to determine this)

```
$ time ./test.bat
"Hello""Hello""Hell
o""Hello""Hello""He
llo""Hello""Hello""
real    0m4.523s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Now if I omit /MANIFEST:embed from my link line, instead I will get test.exe.manifest automatically generated

```
link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:test.exe /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"test.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"test.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH test.obj
```

This is how VS2010 built the tool before migration.  Using the above line, the resulting test.exe.manifest is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This appears the same as what was embedded in the exe file according to the first link command I offered.  Of course after the above link command, there is no manifest file embedded which I can confirm by viewing my test.exe in notepad.  I can now embed the test.exe.manifest file just generated with

```
mt.exe -outputresource:test.exe;#1 -manifest test.exe.manifest
```

And now, if I look at the test.exe in notepad, I see a slightly different formulation of the requestedExecutionLevel line-- it now has what looks to me a more proper  termination.  I'm no expert at xml but I'm used to seeing `<key></key>` pairs, not `<key... \>` which may well be a valid syntax too.

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

And now timing the 100 call bat file runs about 1.5s faster

```
$ time ./test.bat
"Hello""Hello""Hell
o""Hello""Hello""He
llo""Hello""Hello""
real    0m3.095s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

So is this a bug with the way the manifest file is generated with the `<requestedExecutionLevel level=....  \>` instead of `<requestedExecutionLevel level=... ></requestedExecutionLevel>`???

Or something with the way mt.exe embeds what appears to be the exact same manifest??

I was able to build the test.exe the faster way from visual studio by setting property 'Embed Manifest' to 'No' on 'Manifest Tool'>'Input and Output' sheet. I then set 'Additional Manifest Files' to $(IntDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).intermediate.manifest (same value copied from Linker > Manifest File > 'Manifest File').  I insured 'Output Manifest File' was blank and on the 'Manifest Tool' > 'All Options' sheet, I set 'Additional Options' to `/outputresource:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt);#1"`

But we use CMAKE for our build system and I was unable to find a magic incantation to do that from CMAKE.

I tried using mt.exe to extract and re-embed, but the embedded version doesn't seem to change.  If I edit the extracted, then embedding embeds the faster running version, but then I have to edit once to change it, and edit again to put it to what it should be.  So I wound up creating a dummy.manifest file with no UAC options.

dummy.manifest:

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Then the following custom command can correct the issue:

```
IF(WIN32)
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET test
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND "mt.exe" "-inputresource:\"$(TargetDir)\\$(TargetFileName);#1\" -out:\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$(TargetFileName).fix.manifest\""
                   COMMAND "mt.exe" "-outputresource:\"$(TargetDir)\\$(TargetFileName);#1\" -manifest \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dummy.manifest\""
                   COMMAND "mt.exe" "-outputresource:\"$(TargetDir)\\$(TargetFileName);#1\" -manifest \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$(TargetFileName).fix.manifest\""
                   COMMENT "Fixing bad manifest file"
                   )
ENDIF(WIN32)
```

So I have a solution in place that is a bit ugly.

It just seems to me that the odd manifest causes some sort of internal error that takes an extra 15ms on my system to resolve.  If this is true, it seems like a bug in the /MANIFEST:embed option in that it doesn't do what 2010's 2 step embedding did with mt.exe.

Comment: Update-- It turns out that the solution I document above does not fully work.  The generated .exe is fine, but once you copy the .exe it slows down.  In the above example if you `rename test.exe test.bak.exe` then `copy test.bak.exe test.exe`, it slows down.  If you then `del test.ext` followed by `rename test.bak.exe test.exe` the performance is restored.  I've examined all special permissions and see no reason for this.

Comment: Another Update-- I actually logged a call to Microsoft.  They were unable to reproduce and when I reran the timings described above without recompiling, all the timings were fast and consistent.  I then went to the actual product and could also no longer reproduce the issue.  I had tried reboots in between to no avail when I first tried this, but my best guess is that Windows does some sort of maintenance server that caches manifest information somewhere and once that happens,, the performance issue I was seeing goes away.